# JavaScript or Java String Subtraction

Tags: java, javascript, regex

If you are using Java or JavaScript, is there a good way to do something like a String subtraction so that given two strings:

```
org.company.project.component
org.company.project.component.sub_component
```

you just get:

```
sub_component
```

I know that I could just write code to walk the string comparing characters, but I was hoping there was a way to do it in a really compact way.

Another use-case is to find the diff between the strings:

```
org.company.project.component.diff
org.company.project.component.sub_component
```

I actually only want to remove the sections that are identical.

Comment: I don't see how JavaScript is relevant here...

Comment: How isn't it?  You never need to remove a string from another string in javascript?  Granted, all solutions have been posted in java, but that doesn't invalidate the question.

Comment: LOL - okay then, let's tag this as Java/JavaScript/C#/VB.NET/Python/Ruby/erlang/Smalltalk/Lisp/etc... My point is, JavaScript and Java have nothing in common other than syntax shared with C#, C, C++, etc. and this is not really a JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends on *precisely* what you want.  If you're looking for a way to compare strings in the general case -- meaning finding common sub-strings between arbitrary inputs -- then you're looking at something closer to the Levenshtein distance and similar algorithms.  However, if all you need is prefix/suffix comparison, this should work:

```
public static String sub(String a, String b) {
    if (b.startsWith(a)) {
        return b.subString(a.length());
    }

    if (b.endsWith(a)) {
        return b.subString(0, b.length() - a.length());
    }

    return "";
}
```

...or something roughly to that effect.

Comment: Thanks Chris and Daniel (and all the rest of you).  That was amazingly fast.

Comment: This seems like way too much code for what's requested - Erickson's approach (replace string B in string A with empty string) is much simpler and readable.

Comment: @Herb  Agreed, I do like Erickson's (and Chris's) approach much better for readability.  However, his doesn't enforce strict prefix/suffix.  The problem I have is the question is a bit ill-defined: what does String difference really mean?

Answer (score 6):

```
String result = "org.company.project.component.sub_component".replace("org.company.project.component","")
```

Should work...

EDIT: Apache commons libraries are also great to use

As noted below, the StringUtils class does in fact have a method for this:
[StringUtils.remove()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#remove(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Answer (score 3):

At first glance, I thought of RegExp, but adding to the question, you removed that possibility by adding to the start-string ...

So you'll have to make a procedure, that takes every character that are equal out of the resulting string, something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = "org.company.project.component.diff";
var b = "org.company.project.component.sub_component";
var i = 0;
while(a.charAt(i) == b.charAt(i)){
  i++;
}
alert(b.substring(i));
</script>
```

By the way it doesn't have a meaning to set Java and javascript as equals in any context, a popular way of putting it could be:

Java and javascript has four things in common: j - a - v - a !-)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just replace the occurrences of the first string in the second with an empty string ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to get whatever's after the last dot, I find this method easy in Javascript:

```
var baseString = "org.company.project.component.sub_component";
var splitString = baseString.split(".");
var subString = splitString[splitString.length - 1];
```

subString will contain the value you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sub(a, b) {
  return [a, b].join('\x01').match(/^([^\x01]*)[^\x01]*\x01\1(.*)/)[2];
}
```

Though this relies on that the character with code 1 does not appear in any of those strings.

Answer (score -2):

This is a solution for the Javascript end of the question:

```
String.prototype.contracat = function(string){
    var thing = this.valueOf();
    for(var i=0; i<string.length;i++){
        thing=thing.replace(string.charAt(i),"");
    }
    return thing
};
```